# Delay javascript demo function

Tags: javascript, html

how do I delay the text? I had been using `setTimeout()` but is doesn't work.

```
<form name="myForm">
    <input type="submit" value="confirm" onclick="submitFunction()"/>
</form>
<script>
    function submitFunction(){
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hi How are you?";
    }
</script>
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: The code provided doesn't use `setTimeout`. Show us what you've tried with `setTimeout` and describe what hasn't worked.

Comment: You probably did `setTimeout(submitFunction(), 2000)`, ity should be  `setTimeout(submitFunction, 2000)` without the parentheses do that you're passing a reference to three function instead of calling it directly

Comment: Also, I downvoted the question because you can't say you have a problem using setTimeout and not show how you used it

Comment: There are heaps of things that could be wrong, but we're not seeing the faulty code, so we'll have to guess. Given that, I think Tyr's is a good guess, though.

Answer (score 1):

Simply don't use `<input type="submit"/>` in this case. It will cause a page reload and your intended behavior is never shown. Change the input type to `button` will not fire the post behavior so your message is shown below:

```
<form name="myForm">
    <input type="button" value="confirm" onclick="submitFunction()"/>
</form>
<script>
    function submitFunction(){
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hi How are you?";
    }
</script>
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: +1, not knowing what OP has tried, this is a likely cause, but I prefer your first suggestion, not to use `submit` at all, over the provided workaround. You might want to suggest an alternative (i.e. `button`) right there in your answer before jumping to workarounds.

Comment: You're right. This case is so trivial so a workaround makes no sense.